# Prove that $A\subseteq B$ but $A\not= B$

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I think I'm on solid ground for the first half of this proof, however I'm not sure if simply showing an example for the second half is sufficient. Any advice is welcome!

Let $A=\{9^n:n\in\Bbb{Z}\}$, $B=\{3^n:n\in\Bbb{Z}\}$. Prove that $A\subseteq B$ but $A\not= B$.

To begin, assume that $a\in A$. This means that $a=9^n$. Observing that $a=(3)^{2n}$, we can see that $a\in B$. Since $a\in A$ implies $a\in B$, we can say that $A\subseteq B$.

Now suppose $b\in B$. This means that $b=3^n$. However, for certain integers, for example when $n=1$, $b$ is clearly not of the form $9^n$. Therefore we can say that $b\in B$ does not imply $b\in A$. This means that $B\not\subseteq A$ and therefore $A\not=B$.

$\blacksquare$

Comment: You just need a single example of an element in $B$ that is not in $A$.

Comment: $3 \in B$, but there is no integer $n$ s.t. $9^n=3$, so $3$ is not in $A$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$n = 0$ doesn't work because $3^0 = 9^0 = 1$, but the case $n = 1$ is sufficient to show that $A\neq B$. Here's a concise way to write it:

Note that $3^1 = 3$ but $3\neq 9^n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. Thus $3 \in B$ and $3\notin A$. So $B\not\subseteq A$ and $A\neq B$ (using that $A = B$ iff $A\subseteq B$ and $B\subseteq A$).

Comment: Right! thanks for the response! For interests sake, is $n=1$ the only such case? My intuition says that if we defined $A$ and $B$ over $\Bbb{Q}$ instead of $\Bbb{Z}$ then we would have $A=B$. Though I'm not sure how I would prove this

Comment: Definitely not the only case, any odd power will work. You're right about defining $A$ and $B$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. That $A\subseteq B$ is still clear. Conversely take $3^q\in B$, then $3^q = (9^\frac{1}{2})^q = 9^\frac{q}{2}$. But $\frac{q}{2}$ is rational for any rational $q$, so $3^q = 9^\frac{q}{2} \in A$. So $B\subseteq A$ and $A = B$.